# Connect node.js with hadoop platform

Tags: hadoop, iot, bigdata

I want to store and retrieve output generated from node.js on hadoop based tool. Can you suggest me the procedure for the same (which tool i can use and how i can store node.js output with that tool)??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the webHDFS to handle that, if you can give a try on that: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

You can do HTTP API requests to Hadoop to post and get data.